# Multi-Dimensional Arrays and Tables

Tags: javascript, arrays

**This is my code, it's mostly completed. The issue I'm having is trying to get it to display the results in the table as "heads" or "tails" instead of 1's and 0's. I'm sure the problem is within the array I just don't know how to fix it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.**

```js
function update() {
  var startInputVal = Number(document.getElementById("startingNum").value);
  var endInputVal = Number(document.getElementById("endingNum").value);

  if (startInputVal === "") {
    alert("You need to enter a valid value for the start");
  } else if (endInputVal === "") {
    alert("You need to enter a valid value for the end");
  } else {
    var multTable = calcMultTableArray(startInputVal, endInputVal);
    updateTable(multTable);
  }
}


function calcMultTableArray(start, end) {
  var multTable = [];
  var headerRow = [""];
    var heads = (0);
    var tails = (0);
  for (var i = start; i <= end; i++) {
    headerRow.push(i);
  }
  multTable.push(headerRow);

  for (var i = start; i <= end; i++) {
    var row = [i];
    for (var j = start; j <= end; j++) {
      row.push (Math.floor(Math.random() * 2));
              if (row === 0) {
                  heads;

  } else {
     tails;

  }
    }
    multTable.push(row);
  }
  return multTable;
}

function updateTable(multTableArray) {
  var dataTable = document.getElementById("data");
  dataTable.innerHTML = "";

  for (var i = 1; i < multTableArray.length; i++) {
    var row = dataTable.insertRow(-1);
    
    var headerCell = document.createElement("th");
    headerCell.innerHTML = multTableArray[i][0];
    row.appendChild(headerCell);

    for (var j = 1; j < multTableArray[i].length; j++) {
      var numCell = row.insertCell(j);
      numCell.innerHTML = multTableArray[i][j];
    }
  }

  // create header row
  var thead = dataTable.createTHead();
  var row = thead.insertRow(0);
  var tableHeaders = ["Trial#", "Coin1", "Coin2", "Coin3", "Coin4"];
  for (var i = 0; i < tableHeaders.length; i++) {
    var headerCell = document.createElement("th");
    headerCell.innerHTML = tableHeaders[i];
    row.appendChild(headerCell);
  }
}
```

```html
<!--
  Name: Samuel Diaz-Lopez
  Date: 08/02/2020
  Purpose: This page allows the user to pick a number of coins
    to flip and the number of trials. 
-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Flip Coin App</title>
      
    <!--CSS-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
      
    <!--JavaScript-->  
    <script src="scripts/flipcoincalc.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/chromeFileProtocolFix.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div data-role="page">
      <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Coin Flip</h1>
      </div>

      <div data-role="content">
        
        <label for="startingNum">Starting Number: </label>
        <input type="number" id="startingNum" placeholder="Enter the starting number" min="1" max="4">

        <label for="endingNum">Ending Number: </label>
        <input type="number" id="endingNum" placeholder="Enter the ending number" min="1" max="4">
        <br>
        
        <button onclick="update();">Calculate!</button>
        <br>

        <table id="data">
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**This is my code, it's mostly completed. The issue I'm having is trying to get it to display the results in the table as "heads" or "tails" instead of 1's and 0's. I'm sure the problem is within the array I just don't know how to fix it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.**

Comment: It will be nice if you give working example of your code instead of just it's part. For now it is difficult to understand what happening there and where is your problem

Comment: Hi! I edited it and added the HTML as well. It should let you run the code snipped so you can see what I'm talking about now. Thanks for responding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you mean you want to display words `heads` and `tails` instead of 0 and 1? If so it's just minor changes to your code, read comments below

```js
function update() {
  var startInputVal = Number(document.getElementById("startingNum").value);
  var endInputVal = Number(document.getElementById("endingNum").value);

  if (startInputVal === "") {
    alert("You need to enter a valid value for the start");
  } else if (endInputVal === "") {
    alert("You need to enter a valid value for the end");
  } else {
    var multTable = calcMultTableArray(startInputVal, endInputVal);
    updateTable(multTable);
  }
}


function calcMultTableArray(start, end) {
  var multTable = [];
  var headerRow = [""];
    // I didn't get what you was trying
    // to do here, so just commenting it out
    //var heads = (0);
    //var tails = (0);
  for (var i = start; i <= end; i++) {
    headerRow.push(i);
  }
  multTable.push(headerRow);

  for (var i = start; i <= end; i++) {
    var row = [i];
    //
    // Here we do little change
    for (var j = start; j <= end; j++) {
      // Generate random number
      const rn = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
      // If 0, then heads
      if(rn === 0) row.push('Heads');
      // If 1, then tails
      else row.push('Tails');
    }
    //
    multTable.push(row);
  }
  return multTable;
}

function updateTable(multTableArray) {
  var dataTable = document.getElementById("data");
  dataTable.innerHTML = "";

  for (var i = 1; i < multTableArray.length; i++) {
    var row = dataTable.insertRow(-1);
    
    var headerCell = document.createElement("th");
    headerCell.innerHTML = multTableArray[i][0];
    row.appendChild(headerCell);

    for (var j = 1; j < multTableArray[i].length; j++) {
      var numCell = row.insertCell(j);
      numCell.innerHTML = multTableArray[i][j];
    }
  }

  // create header row
  var thead = dataTable.createTHead();
  var row = thead.insertRow(0);
  var tableHeaders = ["Trial#", "Coin1", "Coin2", "Coin3", "Coin4"];
  for (var i = 0; i < tableHeaders.length; i++) {
    var headerCell = document.createElement("th");
    headerCell.innerHTML = tableHeaders[i];
    row.appendChild(headerCell);
  }
}
```

```html
<!--
  Name: Samuel Diaz-Lopez
  Date: 08/02/2020
  Purpose: This page allows the user to pick a number of coins
    to flip and the number of trials. 
-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Flip Coin App</title>
      
    <!--CSS-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
      
    <!--JavaScript-->  
    <script src="scripts/flipcoincalc.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/chromeFileProtocolFix.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div data-role="page">
      <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Coin Flip</h1>
      </div>

      <div data-role="content">
        
        <label for="startingNum">Starting Number: </label>
        <input type="number" id="startingNum" placeholder="Enter the starting number" min="1" max="4">

        <label for="endingNum">Ending Number: </label>
        <input type="number" id="endingNum" placeholder="Enter the ending number" min="1" max="4">
        <br>
        
        <button onclick="update();">Calculate!</button>
        <br>

        <table id="data">
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I was trying to figure out! Thank you so much for your help!